# Obtener el valor de varios input en una fila de una tabla dinamica en JQuery

Tags: jquery, tabla-dinámica

Mi problema radica en que estoy haciendo un modulo para captura de ordenes de un restaurante y utilizo el plugin Typehead para hacer un autossugest a un input. Lo que elijan de las sugerencias, lo voy anexando a una tabla que voy creando con JQuery, les muestro el código:

> Creando la tabla

```
    function agregarOrden(){

    var concepto = $('#txtDescripcion').val();
    var costo = $('#hdCostoAlimento').val();
    var id = $('#hdIdAlimento').val();

     $("#tbOrden").append('<tr><td ><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'+id+'"/></td><td><input type="text" name="cantidad[]" value="1"/></td><td> '+concepto+'</td><td> '+costo+'</td><td>'+costo+'</td><td> NO</td><td> <a href="#" class="delete">Eliminar</a></td></tr>');
        $('.delete').off().click(function(e) {
            $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove();
        });
      }
```

Una vez que agregan y editan la tabla a como va quedar la orden, tengo un botón de guardar, ahí necesito obtener el id que guardo en el input que esta oculto y el valor que tiene el input de cantidad para almacenarlo posteriormente en mi tabla, pero no logro hacerlo. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
   $('#btnGuarda').click(function(){
        var cad="";
        valores=new Array();
        var id = 'id';
        $("#tbOrden tr").each(function (index) {
            $(".idTD").parent("tr").find("td").each(function() {
                //if($(this).html() != "coger valores de la fila"){
                 valores += $(this).text() + " ";
                });
        });
        alert(valores);

        /*$('#tbOrden tr').each(function () {

            var id= $(this).find('td').eq(0).html();
            var cantidad = $(this).find('td').eq(1).html();
            valor=new Array(id,cantidad);
            valores.push(valor);
        });
        alert(valores);*/
    });
```

> Les muestro mi html:

```
 <div class="container">

    <br>
    <form class="form" id="frm"  method="post">
        <input type="hidden" id="hdIdAlimento" name="hdIdAlimento"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="hdCostoAlimento" name="hdCostoAlimento"/>
        <fieldset>

            <div class="card border-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 80rem;">
              <div class="card-header"><h4 class="card-title"><p class="text-primary">Toma de ordenes</p></h4></div>
              <div class="card-body">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2" style="color: white;"> 
                    <h4>Mesa</h4></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4" style="color: white;"><h4>¿Qué deseas ingresar?</h4></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1"><span class="badge badge-info" id="spHelp" style="cursor: pointer;">?</span></div>

                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2"><?php getComboMesas();?></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="lista-color">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtDescripcion" name="txtDescripcion" style="text-transform: uppercase;"/>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" name="btnAgregar" id="btnAgregar" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-check-circle fa-2x"></i></button>
                </div>
                <br>

              </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
      <div class="col-lg-16">
        <div class="bs-component">
          <div class="card border-primary mb-6" style="max-width: 80rem; ">
            <div class="card-header"><h5><p class="text-primary">Orden para la mesa:<span id="spMesa"></span></p></h3></div>
            <div class="card-body" id="divNewOrden">
              <table id="tbOrden" class=" table table-bordered table-striped">
              <tr>
                <th style="visibility: hidden;">Id</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Concepto</th> 
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Servido</th>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <div class="col-sm-10" align="center">
                <button id="btnGuarda" name="btnGuarda" class="btn btn-success ">Guardar</button>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>



</div>
```

Comment: Cual es exactamente el error? no te toma los valores al hacer el submit? porque no realizas un submit del formulario en vez de tomar los valores con jquery? **$( "#form1" ).submit();**

Comment: Que quieres realmente hacer, tomar los valores de cada celda de cada fila y anexarlo a una variable, solo los input o que????